# Android Adaptive icon foreground always too big

Tags: android, android-studio, png, vector-graphics

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I am trying to make an adaptive android app icon. That's the code for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/launcher_backg" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/logo" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

That's what it looks like:
[image: Icon, that does not look like what it should look like]

As you can see, the foreground is way too big. I don't want that, and I don't know how to fix it. I had a workaround, where I just scaled the foreground until it was small enough. The problem then is, that I don't know what the best size is and all, and I'm sure, there is a better solution.

The foreground is a png and the background a vector graphic.

How can I make the foreground to be the perfect size for an android app icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can tell from this [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) the following sizes need to be provided:

In Android 7.1 (API level 25) and earlier, launcher icons were sized at 48 x 48 dp. You must now size your icon layers using the following guidelines:

- Both layers must be sized at 108 x 108 dp.
- The inner 72 x 72 dp of the icon appears within the masked viewport.
- The system reserves the outer 18 dp on each of the 4 sides to create
  interesting visual effects, such as parallax or pulsing.

Comment: Which means that you need to make your icon offset by 18 in each axis for it to be centered in the 108 viewport.

Answer (score 5):

Adding an inset worked for me.

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/launcher_backg" />
    <foreground>
    <inset android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
        android:inset="15%"/>
    </foreground>
</adaptive-icon>
```